# Preventing an HTML form field from being submitted

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want to programmatically allow or hide a form field from being submitted in an HTML5 form. I thought I could just set its CSS `display` attribute to `none`. However, it still gets submitted (just can't be seen). Is there another property I can set rather than removing the element completely from the HTML5 document?

Comment: Just out of curiosity, why do you have a field that you don't want to be submitted?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Simply set `disabled` attribute for the form field, e.g.

```
<input name="test" value="test" disabled="disabled">
```

**REF:** http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html#h-17.12.1

Comment: +1 I thought the possible solution would be `returning false` using js.  this is too simple.

Answer (score 1):

Set the [`disabled`](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/forms.html#enabling-and-disabling-form-controls%3a-the-disabled-attribute) property to the truth value `true`. It corresponds to the HTML attribute (“content attribute” in HTML5 parlance) with the same name but takes truth values. For example, assuming

```
<input name=foo id=foo>
```

you could set, in JavaScript,

```
document.getElementById('foo').disabled = true;
```

This typically changes the appearance of the field, too, by making the background gray.

Setting `display: none`, or *any* CSS setting, has no impact on what gets submitted. CSS is for presentation (rendering), not functionality.