# How to prevent a form field with display:none from being submitted

Tags: drop-down-menu, country

I have a sign-up form which asks users to select a country from a drop down menu.

I have a bit of script that, depending on the country selected by the user, displays a particular Region/State field.

```js
$("#Country").change(function() { 
    
  if ( $(this).val() == "GB") {
   $("#RegionsUS").hide();
   $("#RegionsOTHER").hide();
   $("#RegionsUK").show();
  }
  else if ( $(this).val() == "US") {
   $("#RegionsUS").show();
   $("#RegionsOTHER").hide();
   $("#RegionsUK").hide();
  }
  else {
   $("#RegionsOTHER").show();
   $("#RegionsUS").hide();
   $("#RegionsUK").hide();
  }
 });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>

<select name="Country" id="Country" class="form-control" required>
<option selected>Please select</option>
<option value="GB">United Kingdom</option>
<option value="US">United States</option>
<option value="FR">France</option>
</select>              

<input type="text" id="RegionsOTHER" name="Region" class="form-control" placeholder="Region/State" maxlength="50">

<select id="RegionsUS" name="Region" class="form-control" style="display:none;">
<option value="Alabama">Alabama</option>
</select>

<select id="RegionsUK" name="Region" class="form-control" style="display:none;">
<option value="England">England</option>
<option value="Scotland">Scotand</option>
</select>

</form>
```

Problem is, when the form is submitted, all three region fields are submitted despite two of them always being hidden.

How do I prevent the hidden fields from being submitted with the form?

Thank you.
NJ

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, despite searching pretty much all day yesterday and not seeing the following, my question is obviously very similar to this question:
[Preventing an HTML form field from being submitted](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21137368/preventing-an-html-form-field-from-being-submitted)

So I've edited my function and HTML as follows:

```js
$("#Country").change(function() { 
    
  if ( $(this).val() == 425) {
   $("#RegionsUS").hide();
   document.getElementById('RegionsUS').disabled = true;
   $("#RegionsOTHER").hide();
   document.getElementById('RegionsOTHER').disabled = true;
   $("#RegionsUK").show();
   document.getElementById('RegionsUK').disabled = false;
  }
  else if ( $(this).val() == 426) {
   $("#RegionsUS").show();
   document.getElementById('RegionsUS').disabled = false;
   $("#RegionsOTHER").hide();
   document.getElementById('RegionsOTHER').disabled = true;
   $("#RegionsUK").hide();
   document.getElementById('RegionsUK').disabled = true;
  }
  else {
   $("#RegionsOTHER").show();
   document.getElementById('RegionsOTHER').disabled = false;
   $("#RegionsUS").hide();
   document.getElementById('RegionsUS').disabled = true;
   $("#RegionsUK").hide();
   document.getElementById('RegionsUK').disabled = true;
  }
 });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>

<select name="Country" id="Country" class="form-control" required>
<option selected>Please select</option>
<option value="GB">United Kingdom</option>
<option value="US">United States</option>
<option value="FR">France</option>
</select>              

<input type="text" id="RegionsOTHER" name="Region" class="form-control" placeholder="Region/State" maxlength="50">

<select id="RegionsUS" name="Region" class="form-control" style="display:none;" disabled="disabled">
<option value="Alabama">Alabama</option>
</select>

<select id="RegionsUK" name="Region" class="form-control" style="display:none;" disabled="disabled">
<option value="England">England</option>
<option value="Scotland">Scotand</option>
</select>

</form>
```